# CSS Transitions On Computed Styles

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Is it possible to transition css on what the computed style becomes, not what that style is explicity set to?

**Example**

I have the following CSS/HTML

```css
.grow {
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="grow">
      <ul class="hidden">...</ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then if I use javascript to remove the hidden class the div will logically grow to fit the newly displayed content, however since the height property did not change, the transition does not take effect. Is there a way to overcome this behavior? If it is possible, I'd like to keep the solution to css.

Comment: You cannot animate height based on automatic height, you have to set it to a X % or X px to animate using css, the alternative would be to use JavaScript to get the height when it is automatic then animate from 0px to the new height.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Hope this gets changed in future revisions

Comment: It has no affect on the value of its own height property, but it does on its parent's height property.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I misread your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about two different CSS properties: `height` and `display`. Your transition only applies to `height` property and, even with `display: none;` the element keeps the same `height`.

What you can do, actually, is something like this:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("hid").className = "";
}, 1000);
```

```css
.grow div {
  transition: height 3s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grow .hidden {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="grow">
      <div class="hidden" id="hid">.AaA..</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I could do something like that, I was just hoping there was a way to transition on computed styles instead of the actual style property

Answer (score 0):

As Rolyataylor2 mentioned, you cannot animate automatic dimensions. I've encounted this problem before and have a relatively simple JS-based solution.

Check out [this Codepen](http://codepen.io/ntdb/pen/pJbzww). It uses a small jQuery plugin that I wrote to set the height of the variable-height container to its calculated height based on the heights of its children. It actually clones the element, measures the height, destroys the clone, and explicitly sets the calculated height on the original element.

This is the full code for the plugin and [here's the Gist.](https://gist.github.com/ntdb/6232a619277a43718bc7) It's written in Coffeescript but I can convert it to JS if needed. Cheers!

```
$.fn.extend
  setContentHeight: ->
    return @each ->
      $(@).css('height', $(@).getContentHeight())

  getContentHeight: ->
    elem = $(@).clone().css(
      "height":"auto"
      "display":"block"
    ).appendTo($(@).parent())
    height = elem.css("height")
    elem.remove()
    return height
```

Comment: Thanks ntdb I'm using Angular for this project so I might convert this into a directive. I like to try and keep as much of the view related information in the css as possible but this is helpful. Thanks again.